# deployment issue with .net core console app

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

i've deployed console app to azure web service but faced one problem.
On azure portal I select this web service and then go to console. I typed:

```
dotnet nameofproject.dll
```

and got this message

> bad request

What can be wrong with app?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You don't need to run dotnet <dll> on azure. You just have to publish config file with entry point together with all the files so it can find your dll.

Comment: ok, i fixed it to web app. changed csproj from '...sdk' to '...sdk.web' and added wwwroot then simply deploy as web app. it worked.